# Unable to combine "search value" and "tax_query" using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

This is my function in my template's functions.php.

The problem is that this is working:

```
function ajax_search_action_do(){
    global $wp_query;

    $search = $_POST['search_value'];
    $country   = $_POST['country_value'];

    $args = array(
        's' => $search,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    get_template_part( 'search-results' );

    exit;
}
```

But this is not:

```
function ajax_search_action_do(){
    global $wp_query;

    $search = $_POST['search_value'];
    $country   = $_POST['country_value'];



    $args = array(
        's' => $search,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tax_query' => array(                
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country',               
            'field' => 'id',                      
            'terms' => $country,   
          ),
        ),
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    get_template_part( 'search-results' );

    exit;
}
```

So, when there is search term alone, it's working and I get the right results. But when I try to combine it with the tax_query search term is not working and only tax_query works.

How to make both conditions work together?

THe query that is build:

```
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (8) ) AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%test%'))) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`
```

Comment: inspect the query object and look at the SQL generated by your query. there's no obvious reason why that shouldn't work, in fact a copy/paste of your query works fine for me.

Comment: How to print the query? Via `print_r($wp_query)` ? Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: `$wp_query->request` contains the actual query sent to the DB

Comment: I have updated my question with the query result.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that query. are you sure you have a post with title or content containing `test` and associated to that tax term?

Comment: @Milo it seems OK, but only the "taxonomy" part is working. The "search" part (searching also by the term from searchbox) is not working ;( Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is working in the end ;)

Comment: Are you sure you want field to be "id"? Because that is a numeric value.

Comment: @Otto I think yes. Because dropdown dunction from wordpress has value id, I think it's better than slug or name.

Answer (score 3):

This is a result of a problematic `GROUP BY` clause that's added to WP_Query when `tax_query` is present. It conflicts with the `s` parameter. You can remove the `GROUP BY` entirely to fix it, but you shouldn't do this for every WP_Query. I use the following class often to approach this:

```
/**
 * Search Within a Taxonomy
 * 
 * Support search with tax_query args
 *
 * $query = new WP_Query( array(
 *  'search_tax_query' => true,
 *  's' => $keywords,
 *  'tax_query' => array( array(
 *      'taxonomy' => 'country',               
 *      'field' => 'id',                      
 *      'terms' => $country,   
 *  ) ),
 * ) );
 */
class WP_Query_Taxonomy_Search {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'pre_get_posts' ) );
    }

    public function pre_get_posts( $q ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) return;

        $wp_query_search_tax_query = filter_var( 
            $q->get( 'search_tax_query' ), 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN 
        );

        // WP_Query has 'tax_query', 's' and custom 'search_tax_query' argument passed
        if ( $wp_query_search_tax_query && $q->get( 'tax_query' ) && $q->get( 's' ) ) {
            add_filter( 'posts_groupby', array( $this, 'posts_groupby' ), 10, 1 );
        }
    }

    public function posts_groupby( $groupby ) {
        return '';
    }
}

new WP_Query_Taxonomy_Search();
```

Now you can add the custom `search_tax_query` to WP_Query objects that you want this functionality added to. For example:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'search_tax_query' => true,
    's' => $keywords,
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'country',               
        'field' => 'id',                      
        'terms' => $country,   
    ) ),
) );
```

To explain what's going on here, the problem is caused by an unintended result of the `GROUP BY` MySQL clause that's added to WP_Query objects with a `tax_query` argument. When you combine this with search, we don't want/need this clause. If you remove it, the search results will work as you expect: posts matching a search query (`s`) within a taxonomy (`tax_query`).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to create a wordpress custom search as well and chanced upon [this post](http://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/rick-bjarnason/using-wordpress-query-multiple-taxonomies).

Try this?

```
function ajax_search_action_do(){
    global $wp_query;

    $search = $_POST['search_value'];
    $country   = $_POST['country_value'];

    $args = array(
        's' => $search,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',                
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country',               
            'field' => 'id',                      
            'terms' => $country,   
          ),
        ),
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    get_template_part( 'search-results' );

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you're probably registering your custom taxonomies in the `init` action hook. However, if that's the case, `init` isn't called during an AJAX call.

To get it done, you could, by example, run manually the init action like that :

```
function ajax_search_action_do(){
   do_action('init'); 
   global $wp_query;
   ...
}
```

Comment: `init` is called on AJAX requests.